# What are the Switchboard Plugs URIs?

Tags: release-loki, settings, switchboard

I need to launch Switchboard Plugs directly from command line. What are the settings:// URIs of the Switchboard plugs?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Preference Opening Specification that contains a list of settings URIs used by Switchboard: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N0uqNtVXEFn3cLgNMeN75mP_dpMpCco-7uw5PKow-_Q/edit

But due to the spec is old, there are missing URIs and some are not working for the following options:

- Notifications
- Security & Privacy/Locking
- Printers [Not Working]
- Sound/Input
- Sound/Sound Effects
- Sound/Applications
- Network [Not Working]
- Online Accounts [Not Working]
- About
- Parental Control